# List all removable drives in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, where-object

I am trying to get a list of all removable drives on the PC. I have a USB stick plugged in to test this.

I tried

```
$listDrives = Get-Volume | Select -Property DriveLetter, DriveType |
Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne "`0" -and $_.DriveType -eq '2'}
Write-Output $listDrives
```

but it didn't output anything.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: What's the output when you only run `Get-Volume`?

Comment: Using `Write-Output` i get no result, though with a message box it lists all drives. However when I use `Where-Object` with the message box i also get no output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PowerShell command you provided seems mostly correct for listing removable drives. However, there is a small mistake in your code. The DriveType for removable drives is not '2'; it is 'Removable'. You should update your code to filter by DriveType 'Removable' instead of '2'. Here's the corrected code:

```
$listDrives = Get-Volume | Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, DriveType |
Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne $null -and $_.DriveType -eq 'Removable'}
Write-Output $listDrives
```

Comment: Thank you, now i get an output, at least with a message box.